# Buttons only work on page 1 of pagination using jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, datatable, dspace

I have two buttons inside a FOR, where I can remove or evaluate the registration of users who are still inactive, everything listed on page 1 works already on page 2 and doesn't even make the request, even filtering 2 or 10 per page. Only what is listed on the first page works.

I'm using jQuery and DataTable.

```js
jq = $;
     jq.noConflict();
     // main
     jq(function () {
         jq('#capes').DataTable();
         jq("div#example_length.dataTables_length").children('label').children('select').append(new Option("5", "5"));

         jq(".remove_author_button").click(function (event) {
                var r = confirm("Realmente deseja remover este registro?");
                if (r === true) {
                    var buttonId = jq(this).attr('id').substring(7);
                    window.location = "<%= request.getContextPath() %>/register/manage-authors?operation=remove&id=" + buttonId;
                }
             });

         jq(".check_author_button").click(function (event) {
             console.log('your message');
                var buttonId = jq(this).attr('id').substring(6);
                window.location = "<%= request.getContextPath() %>/register/manage-authors?operation=check&id=" + buttonId;
             });
        });
```

```html
<table id="capes" class="ui celled table" data-order='[[ 0, "asc" ]]' data-page-length='2'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th>&nbsp;</th>
                   <th>&nbsp;</th>
                   <th>Nome</th>
                   <th>E-mail</th>
                   <th>Intituição</th>
                   <th>Departamento</th>
                   <th>Situação</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% if (authorList.size() > 0) { %>               
                <% for (Author author : authorList) {%>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" id="remove_<%= author.getID()%>" value="Remover" class="remove_author_button btn btn-danger"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="check_<%= author.getID()%>" value="Avaliar" class="check_author_button btn btn-success"/></td>                
                    <td><%= author.getEPerson().getFullName()%></td>
                    <td><%= author.getEPerson().getEmail()%></td>
                    <td><%= author.getInstitutionName()%></td>
                    <td><%= author.getDepartment()%></td>
                    <td><%= author.getActive() ? "Ativo" : "Inativo"%></td>
                </tr>
                <% } %>
                <% }%>
```